# How not to get expanded variables in AWK

Tags: bash, awk

Good day,

I was wondering how not to get expanded variables in AWK.

variable to pass:`achi`

But, when I try with:

```
awk -F, -v var1="achi" '$(NF-1)~var1' file
```

It just does not work. It prints all lines that match `achi`.

I'll appreciate some insights to do it properly.

**Input**

```
achi, francia
nachi, peru
universidad achi, japon
achito, suecia
```

**Expected Output**

```
achi, francia
```

Comment: `'$(NF-1)~"\b"var1"\b"'` Those are strings, you need to quote them. But all of those will also get you `universidad achi, japon` in your output I believe.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "expanded variables"?

Comment: when I want to find the lines with only the word `achi` _In the example of input_. The command line matches and prints the lines with: `nachi`,`universidad achi`,`achito`. I just want that the command line print me the line that only have the word at the specific `NF`.

Comment: @anubhava Thank to show me. The properly answer is that I do not know how to count characters in awk, like in bash. The other properly answer on my preferences between bash or awk, is that awk process faster big data files.

Comment: We can help but need to know why `universidad achi` record shouldn't be there in output even though it has regex `\bachi\b`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be trying to test equivalence with the pattern matching operator `~`. The proper operator to test equivalence is `==`.

```
awk -F, -v var1="achi" '$(NF-1)==var1' file
```

If you are expecting more fields you should take into account that your values are separated with a comma **and** a space, this can be done using `", "` as  the field separator.

```
awk -F", " -v var1="achi" '$(NF-1)==var1'
```